# Unity Calling a method from a script of another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods

In my process of using Unity to get some practical coding experience, I decided to basically make a game manager object that stores methods that an enemy object can call upon and determine its behavior. The issue I am having, is that I am unable to do so, despite my methods work when used within the enemy object itself.

I did research on how to do it and felt for sure that I coded correctly, but evidently not. So the below is my code.

The code on the enemy object:

```
    private GameObject gameManager;
    private ForTesting forTesting;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager");
        forTesting = gameManager.GetComponent<ForTesting>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        forTesting.Test();

    }
```

The code on the GameManager (empty)object ForTesting script

```
    public void Test()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 20 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

I also tested adding the ForTesting script to the enemy object itself, and simply changed void Start() to

```
forTesting = GetComponent<ForTesting>();
```

The above worked, which I personally feel would still work for the project I'm working on, but I don't want to proceed without first understanding what went wrong with my initial implementation, and I am unsure which method is better, or if there exists a better one.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: What happened when you tried the first attempt? Compilation error? Runtime error? If so, please include the error details in the question. Did it run but behave differently to what you're expecting? If so, please describe the expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: There is no error code or anything. The object simply stayed in place instead of moving forward. The expected behavior worked, however, if I put the script component into the object itself rather than another object.